# Not Able to use ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 4 after users.user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']

Tags: php, sql

I am not able to use

```
order by rand() limit 5
```

after

```
['user_id']
```

Is there any way to do that, please help.

```
$sqlstate = "select * from questions, users where users.category_id=questions.category_id and users.user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id'] order by rand() limit 5;
```

Comment: Print your query & share that with us.

Comment: $sqlstate = "select * from questions, users where users.category_id=questions.category_id and users.user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id'] order by rand() limit 5;

After user this code I am getting error.

Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'order' (T_STRING) in

Comment: Solved Thanks

$sqlstate = "select * from questions, users where users.category_id=questions.category_id and users.user_id<>".$_SESSION['user_id']." order by rand() limit 2";

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix the string and concatenation.

```
$sqlstate = "select * from questions, users where users.category_id=questions.category_id and users.user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." order by rand() limit 5";
```

Alternately, since you seem to be using PHP, you can just use the variable inside the double quotes:

```
$sqlstate = "select * from questions, users where users.category_id=questions.category_id and users.user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'] order by rand() limit 5";
```